# Не получается подключится к БД FoxPro через мост jdbc:odbc

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, dbf

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
У меня стоит Windows 10 64x, jdk1.7.0_79 64x. Есть БД на FoxPro путь - d:\comp\database\base.dbc
Я работаю с MySQL то все прекрасно получается. А к БД на FoxPro не получается подключится.

```
  try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver") ;
        System.out.println("JdbcOdbcDriver успешно загружен");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Не удалось загрузить JdbcOdbcDriver, ошибка № " + e);
    }
```

Драйвер загружает успешно.

в "Источники данных ODBC (32-разрядная версия)" в вкладке "Пользовательский DNS" я добавил драйвер "Microsoft FoxPro VFP Driver (*.dbf)"

Data Source Name: я указал Database

Description: я указал DBF

Database type я выбрал Visual FoxPro Database (.DBC)

и в Path: я выбрал путь d:\comp\database\base.dbc

потом код дальше:

```
 String url="jdbc:odbc:Database";
 try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    if (!con.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Соединение c БД FoxPro успешно установлено");
    }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Невозможно соединиться БД FoxPro, ошибка № " + e);
 }
```

но мне выдает ошибку:

```
Невозможно соединиться БД FoxPro, ошибка № java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] В указанном DSN архитектура драйвера и архитектура приложения не соответствуют друг другу.
```

Я начинаю думать, что проблема в том, что драйвер для FoxPro х86. Тогда как обойти эту проблему? Устанавливать 32-х разрядную ОС или может хватит jdk для x86? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обойти эту проблему. Уверен, что профессионалы уже столкнулись с этим и знают как это решается.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас такая проблема, о=тогда надо просто скачать jdk7 x86 и установить его. 32-разрядная версия никак не перепишет и не заменит и не повлияет на 64-разрядную версию. Потом в Project Structure... указать путь к этому jdk. Скорее всего это будет c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

1. Драйвер должен быть той же разрядности, что и программа обращающаяся к этому драйверу.
2. Драйверы для *.dbf не знают про *.dbc. Или *.dbf и указание конкретного файла (хотя иногда можно и каталог с файлами), или указание на dbc, но использовать драйвер знающий именно про базу данных VFP.